# JSON Schema object types not working for $ref definitions

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator, python-jsonschema

I am using `JSON Schema Draft-07`. I am having a JSON Schema like below that works as expected

```
{
"tests": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "name",
        "desc"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "desc": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

But if I `refer` the same `type` using `definition`, `siblings` `properties\rules` doesn't take affect , for e.g.

`JSON Schema Store`

```
{
  "my-schema.json": {
    "$id": "my-schema.json",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "definitions": {
      "objectParameter": {
        "type": "object"
      }
    },
    "properties": {
      "tests": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/objectParameter",
        "properties": {
          "desc": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        },
        "required": [
          "name",
          "desc"
        ]
      }
    },
    "required": [
      "tests"
    ],
    "type": "object"
  }
}
```

Not sure what's the difference `$ref` is bringing here.
Validation Data : `"tests": {"namer": "12", "desc": "12"}` or `"tests": {}` should fail but getting passed .

Answer (score 1):

"doesn't work" isn't very specific, but is it possible you are using an implementation that follows draft specification version 7 or earlier, in which the presence of a `$ref` keyword nullifies the effect of any other sibling keywords?  If so, you can resolve the situation by wrapping an "allOf" around the subschemas:

```
"allOf": [
  { "$ref": ... },
  {
    "required": ...,
    "properties": { ... }
  }
]
```

Comment: I  have updated my post to make it more specific. I have also updated the exact `JSON Schema Store` used to validate the data, there is no  any other implementation of `$ref` except the mentioned one .

Comment: Ok, so as I said -- if you are using draft 7 or earlier (which you are), when $ref is present, none of the other keywords that are siblings to it will have any effect. You need to separate them with an `allOf`.